# How to obtain Graph object for Session from saved graph.pb

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have created a tensorflow `Graph`. I can load it with, for example

```
with tf.gfile.FastGFile(modelFullPath, 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
```

which places the graph defined in the protobuffer file as the default graph for the moment. If I now create a session, this graph will be used as the current graph.

Trying to save the serialized `graph_def` object to a variable and launch a `Session` as

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph_def) as sess:
```

ends with an expected error

```
TypeError: graph must be a tf.Graph, but got <class 'tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2.GraphDef'>
```

I have a use case where I have to change between multiple graphs. With the presented approach I can clear the default graph and load a new one, which has the drawback of having to call the import functions repeatedly.

Question is, from my `graph.pb`, how is a `Graph` object `my_graph` obtained, so it would be possible to use

```
with tf.Session(graph=my_graph) as sess:
```

and create sessions without reloading graphs from `graph.pb` files?

Comment: can you please tell me how you managed to do this?

Comment: @HaraHaraMahadevaki Just like the accepted answer suggested.

Comment: thank you... it is bit slow...any workaround to improve the speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own graph and set it as default for import operation:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
graph1 = tf.Graph()
graph2 = tf.Graph()
with graph1.as_default():
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def1) # graph_def1 loaded somewhere

with graph2.as_default():
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def2) # graph_def2 loaded somewhere

session1 = tf.Session(graph=graph1)
session2 = tf.Session(graph=graph2)
```

Comment: how do i create my own graph from the pb file?